# OpenOffice crashes after I run it after installation

Tags: linux, installation, openoffice

I've installed OpenOffice 3.2.1 on Linux s390x System z server after downloading the OOo_3.2.1_Linux_S390X_install-rpm_en-US.tar.gz file from http://download.openoffice.org/other.html. I installed it using the following command `rpm -ihv  *.rpm`. Now everything installs successfully with no errors. But when I `cd /opt/openoffice.org3/program` and type in `soffice` to start OpenOffice I see the splash screen for a second, the loading bar moving to around 33% before it crashes and shuts down with no errors or exceptions. Have tried uninstalling and installing many times with no sucess whatsoever. Any know what's going on?

Last few lines of `strace ./soffice` added below, not sure it'll help.

```
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x80049ab0, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x800376c8, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 78}], 0, NULL) = 26737
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, 0x3fffff8a2a4, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
sigreturn()                             = ? (mask now [])
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL}, {0x800376c8, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried installing it with your distro's package manager? It's the standard way to install software on linux.

Comment: No package managers on this thing

Comment: If you're using an `rpm` file, you're using a package manager.

Comment: @RandolphWest Right, well in that case I guess I am using one

Comment: Try running "strace soffice" and update your question with the last few lines (if they seem relevant).

Comment: I'm not an strace expert. It looks as if you might be showing lines that all *follow* the crash. Can you maybe upload the entire strace output somewhere and link to it in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Turns out the server was missing a fonts folder at the location `/usr/share/fonts`. In the strace output there were 2300 references to `fonts`, seemed as if OpenOffice was searching all over for some fonts. I compared the fonts relate folders and packages with another server (on which OpenOffice was running fine) and found there was an extra `/usr/share/fonts/java` folder on the other server. Zipped that folder and copied it over to this server and OpenOffice started up.

Answer (score 0):

Start OOo with "oowriter" or "oocalc" or one of the other actual application names, not "soffice". It ain't StarOffice any more! :)

Comment: There's no 'oowriter' in here, there's an 'swriter' here and that does the same.